# Return an entire row with excel

Tags: excel

I'd like to return all the values for Linda, with minimal manual changing of formulas.

Is there a formula I can use to populate Linda's data either all at once, or with dragging?

[image]

Comment: You can use the `VLOOKUP` function to do it cell by cell. I do not think there is any way to get the entire row.

Comment: Consider using `MATCH()` and `INDEX()`

Comment: How would you use MATCH in combination with INDEX to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B8:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH($A8,$A:$A,0))
```

And drag across.

Comment: Could I use this if I have a large data set (more names) and I needed to return values for multiple names without changing the formula manually each time? In the same way one might VLOOKUP and then drag down a column.

Comment: Yes, just drag it over and down the list.  In your example if you added Tom below Linda and dragged this formula over and down it would fill both their individual information.

Answer (score 0):

In **B8** enter:

```
=INDEX(B1:B4,MATCH($A$8,$A1:$A4,0))
```

and copy across